# How to validate with regular expression and display error message in xeditable

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I am using xeditable in my project.

I need to validate each and every field,

how to do validation using ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" and show error message if the input value does not match the pattern.

can any one guide me how can i proceed with this.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpgD4/270/)

```
$scope.checkName = function(data) {
console.log("user.name.onbeforesave:", data)
if (data !== 'awesome') {
  return "Username should be `awesome`";
}
```

};

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use ng-pattern?  Can you not change the function to use the regexp?

This works:

```
 $scope.checkName = function(data) {
    console.log("user.name.onbeforesave:", data)
    if (!data.match(/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/)) {
      return "Only spaces and letters allowed";
    }
  }
```